# Reading tabs (music) with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm developing an application on AngularJs. It reads the tablature of a song (the ones that come with the music) and you put numbers according to the cord on the guitar.

Basically I need something that looks like this:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

where every line represents one cord on the guitar. The idea is that this space only receives numbers and some letters. When someone click on the element only one `-` can be selected. I've done this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='Lector'>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="controller.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <title>Lector partituras</title>
</head>
<body ng-controller = 'lectorController' ng-cloack>

<TEXTAREA data-drag="true" data-drop="true" rows=6 cols=80 name="txtsugerencias" ng-model = "partitura" ng-change="validar()"></TEXTAREA><BR>

<p ng-model="mensaje" >{{mensaje}}</p>
</body>

</html>
```

And for my controller this:

```
var app = angular.module('Lector', []);

app.controller('lectorController', function($scope, $http)
{
    $scope.partitura="";
    $scope.mensaje = "SOy un mensaje";
    for (var i = 0; i < 300; i++) {

        $scope.partitura= $scope.partitura+ "-";
    }
    /*for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; i < 79; i++) {
            $scope.partitura= $scope.partitura+"-";
        }
        $scope.partitura= $scope.partitura+ "\n";
    }
    $scope.validar = function()
    {

        var nuevopart = "";
        for (var i = 0; i <$scope.partitura.length; i++) 
        {
            var letra = $scope.partitura.charAt(i);
            if(letra =="-")
                nuevopart = nuevopart + letra;
            else
                alert(letra);
            if(!esNumero(letra))
            {
                nuevopart = nuevopart + "-";
            }

        }
        alert(nuevopart);
    }
    $scope.esNumero = function(str)
    {
        var esNumero = true;
        for (var i = 1; i <=6 && esNumero; i++) 
        {
            if(str != i)
                esNumero = false;
        }
        alert("LETRA: "+str +" ES NUMERO");
        return esNumero;
    }*/

});
```

But I'm not sure that a textarea be the perfect component for this. I also don't know how to make it possible to only select one character and avoid spaces, letters.

Comment: You're asking a lot in this question... It might be easier if you broke it down to individual problems, figure each out individually, then move on to the next problem. Right now, the question is quite broad.